# Solving linear equations error in python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following system of linear equations:

```
#x0 + 1/10 * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) = 10
#x1 + 1/15 * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5) = 20
#x2 + 1/21 * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6) = 30
```

To do so I am doing:

`a = np.array([[1,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,0,0],[0,1+1/15,1/15,1/15,1/15,1/15,0],[0,1/21,1+1/21,1/21,1/21,1/21]])
b=np.array([10,20,30])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)`

For which I get the following error:

```
LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong? The array has correct entries as I checked. I am following the example [here](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/27/Solving-linear-equations/)

Comment: The last row contains only 6 numbers. But the linalg expect square matrix anyway (because of the A^-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as though there is an error in the last line of the matrix - I count 5 commas rather than 6.

With your version `a.shape` is `(3,)`

```
a = np.array([[1,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,0,0],[0,1+1/15,1/15,1/15,1/15,1/15,0],[0,1/21,1+1/21,1/21,1/21,1/21,1/21]])
```

With the missing element as above, `a.shape` is `(3,7)` which seems correct.

Also as noted in the comment, you have 7 unknowns and only 3 equations so you have an [underdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system).

Comment: Does having the undetermined system leads to: LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, but yes that would make sense. You need the same number of (independent) equations as unknowns.